# Office addin custom task pane display issue

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins, .net-4.8, customtaskpane

I have created a c# vsto office addin that exposes a custom task pane.

All office task pane need to be created using a Sytem.Windows.Forms.UserControl. In this userControl I have added an System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost to be able to support WPF in the task pane.

All this was working very well until I faced a display issue with a combobox item in a multi monitor with different DPI environment.

I'm using two monitors:

First monitor, set as main monitor:

- Resolution: 3840*2160
- Size of text, apps, and other items: 200%

Second monitor:

- Resolution: 1920*1080
- Size of text, apps, and other items: 100%

When opening PowerPoint directly from the second monitor the items of the combobox are not clickable

I have created a reproducible repo with the minimum code needed and explanations with a video showing the behavior: https://github.com/guillaumepoweruser/TaskPaneAddIn

I have read much on the subject of DPI and cannot find any way to fix this ComboBox issue. I have tried the online solutions I have found such as creating an app.config, creating and app.manifest or calling a NativeMethods.SetProcessDpiAwareness as the very begining in ThisAddIn_Startup.

I'm struggling with this, any help will be very welcome!

Comment: Do you get the same issue with windows forms controls?

Comment: As far as I know WPF had some issues when using on task panes in Office. This were known issues you could find on the MS Connect site.